# Asp.Net MVC 5 - how to Implement Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to update the .NET Framework of our app that is created from ASP.NET MVC 5

I just discovered that it was using the Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault which was stated in nugget as deprecated version and recommends to use Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets

however, implemented in the code is like so:

```
public static string GetSecretWithCert(string secretNode)
{

    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
    string keyVaultName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyVaultName"];
    string keyVaultCertificateThumbprint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KvThumbprint"];


    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(secretNode)) return string.Empty;

    var secretUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/secrets/{secretNode}";

    KeyVaultClient keyClient = new KeyVaultClient(async (authority, resource, scope) =>
    {
        AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, null);
        X509Certificate2 certificate;
        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        ClientAssertionCertificate clientAssertionCertificate;

        try
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

            var certificateCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, keyVaultCertificateThumbprint, false);

            if (certificateCollection.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("Certificate not installed in the store");
            }

            certificate = certificateCollection[0];

            clientAssertionCertificate = new ClientAssertionCertificate(clientId, certificate);

            var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientAssertionCertificate).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw (ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
            authenticationContext = null;
            certificate = null;
            clientAssertionCertificate = null;
        }


    });

    SecretBundle secret = null;

    try
    {
        // changed to a sync call with GetAwaiter and GetResult
        secret = keyClient.GetSecretAsync(secretUri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }

    return (secret?.Value);
}
```

How can I translate the codes above with the Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets Library's codes?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the sample code below, details see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/security.keyvault.secrets-readme).

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("https://myvault.azure.vaults.net/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync("secret1");
```

The code above uses `DefaultAzureCredential` to auth, [the following credential types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet) if enabled will be tried, in your original code, it uses the certificate to get the token, if you still want to keep this, use [`ClientCertificateCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.clientcertificatecredential?view=azure-dotnet) instead of `DefaultAzureCredential` in the code above.

Comment: How can I put ClientCertificateCredential? The secretclient only accepts TokenCredential class..

Comment: Ohh i lack library which is Azure.Core

Comment: After implementing this, I get error where it looks for version 4.0.4 of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource